# GRUB : file not found after an update from Debian Wheezy to Jessie

Tags: debian, grub2

I have an online server which was running Debian Wheezy. Yesterday, I updated it to Jessie.

I had no problems during the upgrade, but when I rebooted the machine, it didn't go live.

I'm able to access the machine through a KVM, which shows me a grub prompt, after an error message that it can't find a file (but doesn't tell which one).

After some searches on the web, I was able to make the OS boot successfully using the following commands:

```
linux (hd0,msdos1)/vmlinuz-3.16.0-4-646-pae root=/dev/sda4
initrd (hd0,msdos1)/initrd.img-3.16.0-4-686-pae
boot
```

FYI, here are the values of $prefix and $root:

```
echo $root
hd0,msdos4

echo $prefix
(hd0,msdos1)/grub
```

Now that the OS was started, I could log in normally and use the following commands to repair GRUB:

```
sudo update-grub
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-4-686-pae
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-4-686-pae
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-4-686-pae
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-4-686-pae
done
```

And

```
sudo grub-mkconfig

Generating grub configuration file ...
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="0"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi


function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}
function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,msdos4'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos4 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos4 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos4 --hint='hd0,msdos4'  87b34327-2d5b-429e-8cdb-5fd379f12fa2
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 87b34327-2d5b-429e-8cdb-5fd379f12fa2
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=640x480
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=-1
else
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=menu
    set timeout=5
  # Fallback normal timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
  # unavailable.
  else
    set timeout=5
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=cyan/blue
set menu_color_highlight=white/blue
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
        set gfxpayload="${1}"
}
set linux_gfx_mode=
export linux_gfx_mode

Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-4-686-pae
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-4-686-pae
menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-87b34327-2d5b-429e-8cdb-5fd379f12fa2' {
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1 --hint='hd0,msdos1'  9db62512-db87-4bbd-8dfd-02a642f0f772
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 9db62512-db87-4bbd-8dfd-02a642f0f772
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.16.0-4-686-pae ...'
        linux   /vmlinuz-3.16.0-4-686-pae root=UUID=87b34327-2d5b-429e-8cdb-5fd379f12fa2 ro  quiet
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /initrd.img-3.16.0-4-686-pae
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Debian GNU/Linux' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-87b34327-2d5b-429e-8cdb-5fd379f12fa2' {
        menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 3.16.0-4-686-pae' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.16.0-4-686-pae-advanced-87b34327-2d5b-429e-8cdb-5fd379f12fa2' {
                load_video
                insmod gzio
                if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
                insmod part_msdos
                insmod ext2
                set root='hd0,msdos1'
                if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1 --hint='hd0,msdos1'  9db62512-db87-4bbd-8dfd-02a642f0f772
                else
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 9db62512-db87-4bbd-8dfd-02a642f0f772
                fi
                echo    'Loading Linux 3.16.0-4-686-pae ...'
                linux   /vmlinuz-3.16.0-4-686-pae root=UUID=87b34327-2d5b-429e-8cdb-5fd379f12fa2 ro  quiet
                echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
                initrd  /initrd.img-3.16.0-4-686-pae
        }
        menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 3.16.0-4-686-pae (sysvinit)' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.16.0-4-686-pae-init-sysvinit-87b34327-2d5b-429e-8cdb-5fd379f12fa2' {
                load_video
                insmod gzio
                if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
                insmod part_msdos
                insmod ext2
                set root='hd0,msdos1'
                if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1 --hint='hd0,msdos1'  9db62512-db87-4bbd-8dfd-02a642f0f772
                else
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 9db62512-db87-4bbd-8dfd-02a642f0f772
                fi
                echo    'Loading Linux 3.16.0-4-686-pae ...'
                linux   /vmlinuz-3.16.0-4-686-pae root=UUID=87b34327-2d5b-429e-8cdb-5fd379f12fa2 ro  quiet init=/lib/sysvinit/init
                echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
                initrd  /initrd.img-3.16.0-4-686-pae
        }
 menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 3.16.0-4-686-pae (recovery mode)' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.16.0-4-686-pae-recovery-87b34327-2d5b-429e-8cdb-5fd379f12fa2' {
                load_video
                insmod gzio
                if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
                insmod part_msdos
                insmod ext2
                set root='hd0,msdos1'
                if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1 --hint='hd0,msdos1'  9db62512-db87-4bbd-8dfd-02a642f0f772
                else
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 9db62512-db87-4bbd-8dfd-02a642f0f772
                fi
                echo    'Loading Linux 3.16.0-4-686-pae ...'
                linux   /vmlinuz-3.16.0-4-686-pae root=UUID=87b34327-2d5b-429e-8cdb-5fd379f12fa2 ro single
                echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
                initrd  /initrd.img-3.16.0-4-686-pae
        }
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-4-686-pae
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-4-686-pae
        menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 3.2.0-4-686-pae' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.2.0-4-686-pae-advanced-87b34327-2d5b-429e-8cdb-5fd379f12fa2' {
                load_video
                insmod gzio
                if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
                insmod part_msdos
                insmod ext2
                set root='hd0,msdos1'
                if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1 --hint='hd0,msdos1'  9db62512-db87-4bbd-8dfd-02a642f0f772
                else
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 9db62512-db87-4bbd-8dfd-02a642f0f772
                fi
                echo    'Loading Linux 3.2.0-4-686-pae ...'
                linux   /vmlinuz-3.2.0-4-686-pae root=UUID=87b34327-2d5b-429e-8cdb-5fd379f12fa2 ro  quiet
                echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
                initrd  /initrd.img-3.2.0-4-686-pae
        }
        menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 3.2.0-4-686-pae (sysvinit)' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.2.0-4-686-pae-init-sysvinit-87b34327-2d5b-429e-8cdb-5fd379f12fa2' {
                load_video
                insmod gzio
                if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
                insmod part_msdos
                insmod ext2
                set root='hd0,msdos1'
                if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1 --hint='hd0,msdos1'  9db62512-db87-4bbd-8dfd-02a642f0f772
                else
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 9db62512-db87-4bbd-8dfd-02a642f0f772
                fi
                echo    'Loading Linux 3.2.0-4-686-pae ...'
                linux   /vmlinuz-3.2.0-4-686-pae root=UUID=87b34327-2d5b-429e-8cdb-5fd379f12fa2 ro  quiet init=/lib/sysvinit/init
                echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
                initrd  /initrd.img-3.2.0-4-686-pae
        }
menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 3.2.0-4-686-pae (recovery mode)' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.2.0-4-686-pae-recovery-87b34327-2d5b-429e-8cdb-5fd379f12fa2' {
                load_video
                insmod gzio
                if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
                insmod part_msdos
                insmod ext2
                set root='hd0,msdos1'
                if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1 --hint='hd0,msdos1'  9db62512-db87-4bbd-8dfd-02a642f0f772
                else
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 9db62512-db87-4bbd-8dfd-02a642f0f772
                fi
                echo    'Loading Linux 3.2.0-4-686-pae ...'
                linux   /vmlinuz-3.2.0-4-686-pae root=UUID=87b34327-2d5b-429e-8cdb-5fd379f12fa2 ro single
                echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
                initrd  /initrd.img-3.2.0-4-686-pae
        }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
done
```

After that, I rebooted to check everything was fine, but I still have the same problem.

A last information : I updated the variable GRUB_TIMEOUT to -1 (checked with 180 too) in /etc/default/grub, but when I restart, I can't see the prompt. I go directly to the GRUB prompt.

What can I do to fix the problem? I'm a bit clueless at the moment.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

And now it works, after a:

sudo grub-install /dev/sda

The command I was afraid to write :) But it turns out it had to be done...